# CI Database Name

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, database-design, database-connection

I have a problem in connecting database in Codeigniter , cause my database name is "database-db_sample", so I'm wondering if the -(hypen) in my db name is the reason why I got an error,

This is the error i got

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to select the specified database: database-db_sample

Can someone tell me what's I had done wrong, 
This is my db config

```
$db['online']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['online']['username'] = "root";
$db['online']['password'] = "";
$db['online']['database'] = "database-db_sample";
$db['online']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['online']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['online']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['online']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['online']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['online']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['online']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['online']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: are you sure that is your db name? is your config correct? It doesnt seem like the hypen is the cause of your error...

Comment: The hyphen should be allowed, the [permitted characters can be viewed here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html). I think you may need to change your last three configs from `default` to  `online`. Or change all of the `online` values to `default`.

Comment: i'm sure of that, cause I try my other db and it works for me using that config, but this db name give me an error, and the problem is I cant modify it's name cause It was already used a years ago. . .

Comment: I already change it, and nothing happens, actually I will be using 2 database, and that db is working in our online site, and but when I try to use it, it doesn't work. . .

Comment: make sure you have created the database with the same name

Comment: @raheel I think you have some point, but like I said I will be using 2 databases in the same time, and the other db that I use is the same with the application that I'm using. . . .

Comment: I forgot to say that I already try to use other db different with my application name, and it works, so i'm just wondering what I'm I missing with my config

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either you don't have proper permissions set to root or mySQL doesn't like your use of hyphens.

So if you want to start new from phpMyAdmin. Start by going to your localhost->phpMyAdmin->privileges tab->add new user. Type in a username and use localhost then check the box for "create a database with same name...". That's it! **Just don't use hyphens**. Your database will have the same name as your username with all proper permissions.